# SSH login through public Ip on local network machine

Tags: networking

Let there are 10 computers on local network and I want to have ssh login to them. I am having 
public Ip of network and also local Ip(private Ip) of machines. So how can I perform ssh login
to any device from outside network??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have access on router/firewall ( public ip) , you can redirect some port from public to private

public:2221 to private1:22

public:2222 to private2:22

and so on.

Comment: OK I dont want port forwarding. Can you tell me how to implement reverse ssh in linux. Because I am not having access of router